# Can't boot eOS 5.1 because of missing mmx64.efi

Tags: boot, uefi, efi

> Failed to open \EFI\BOOT\mmx64.efi - Not Found
>
> Failed to load image \EFI\BOOT\mmx64.efi: Not Found
>
> Failed to start MokManager: Not Found
>
> Somethinghas gone seriously wrong: import_mok_state() failed : Not
>   Found

On Acer ES1-512. 
When installed in Legacy mode it boot's and installs with 0 problems. But when I go to shut down or restart - nothing, stays on black screen till I press the power button.

Didn't have problems with eOS 5. It was working fine in UEFi mode.

Some other distros are acting the same way - KDE Neon and the latest Mint 19.3 are doing the same for me. But Xubuntu and Lubuntu - both 19.10 for example work perfectly fine in UEFI mode.

Please take a look and find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Boot an Elementary OS Live USB stick, go into your hard disk drive's /boot/efi folder and rename the file grubx64.efi to mmx64.efi. Save. Restart the machine. Check will it boot.

Other possible solutions are here: [Can't install Ubuntu 18.10 on XPS 15 - EFI\BOOT\mmx64.efi not found](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1085550/cant-install-ubuntu-18-10-on-xps-15-efi-boot-mmx64-efi-not-found)

Comment: This doesn't fix the problem. Guess you just read somewhere about it. Hope someone from the developers sees this and finds a way to fix it.